# Load CSV then return list of rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, csv

I have the following working code that reads a csv file with two columns by ~500 rows, then return a list of lists for both columns and convert the values to float.

I'm reading around 200k files per test case, so a total of ~5M .csv files. It's taking around 1,5 min to read 200k and to return the list.

I did a benchmark that only read the .csvs and it takes around 5s, so the bottleneck is in the list comprehension + float conversion.

Is it possible to speed things up? I already tried pandas, numpy loadtxt and genfromtxt. All of the alternatives I've tried are very slow comparing to what I have so far.

Example of a .csv file content:

```
1.000e-08, -1.432e-07
1.001e-08, 7.992e-07
1.003e-08, -1.838e-05
# continues for more 500 lines
```

## Some benchmarks:

Reading 200k .csv files with 500 lines and 2 columns like the example above:

#### Using Pandas: 6m9s (369s)

```py
def read_csv_return_list_of_rows(csv_file, _delimiter):
    df=pd.read_csv(csv_file, sep=_delimiter,header=None)
    return df.astype('float').values
```

#### Using NumPy's genfromtxt: 3m58s (238s)

```py
def read_csv_return_list_of_rows(csv_file, _delimiter):
    return np.genfromtxt(csv_file, delimiter=_delimiter)
```

#### Using CSV.reader from the stdlib: 1m31s (91s)

```py
def read_csv_return_list_of_rows(csv_file, _delimiter):
    with open(csv_file, 'r') as f_read:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(f_read, delimiter = _delimiter)
        csv_file_list = [[float(i) for i in row] for row in csv_reader]
    return csv_file_list
```

If I remove the float() from the last implementation the time decreases significantly as well as if I remove the list comprehension, so these two are the issues here.

## From the answers:

#### @SpghttCd: 1m27s (87s)

Comment: Just a minor comment, you don't need to initiate an empty list, list comprehension already creates the list for you.

Comment: True, I forgot to remove actually. Thx.

Comment: Now, my question is, is pandas using `.astype('float').values` slower than the nested list comprehension? Let alone numpy should be faster than pandas.

Comment: @Celius Could you write an answer please? I used `df=pd.read_csv(csv_file, sep=_delimiter,header=None)` and then `df.values` to obtain the list. You mean to use `df.astype('float').values`? If this is the case I just tried and it takes 6m9s to finish.

Comment: @Celius I updated the question with some benchmarks.

Comment: You mention that the issue is in the context of test cases. Would it be an option to test the read/convert once and cache it afterwards for the other test cases?

Comment: @mrks You mean to save the loaded results in memory and reuse them later? If so, the issue is the footprint in memory. That's why I'm using separate files instead of a JSON (or similar) with all the results.

Comment: @Raphael You could write your test cases into an sqlite database, for example. That would avoid the repeated conversion and you would not need to have them all in memory. That being said, if you always have the 2-col float format, then why not write/read from raw binary files? You could create them with ```numpy.ndarray.tofile```.

Comment: @mrks Thanks for the suggestion, I will take a look at it. I used hdf5 to avoid using sqllite since I think it's too much for this simple case and because I need to share the .csv files. 50% of the time is spent converting from str to float. Since others may need to open with another language or even in excel, can we use `numpy.ndarray.tofile` as .csv in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't test, so just a proposal how I would have tried:

```
def read_csv_return_list_of_rows_gen(csv_file, _delimiter):
    with open(csv_file, 'r') as f_read:
        for line in f_read:
            yield [float(i) for i in line.split(_delimiter)]

result = list(read_csv_return_list_of_rows_gen(filename, ','))
```

Comment: Thank you. I tested your solution and it takes 1m27s against 1m31s (my solution) to read and compute 200k .csv files with 500 lines and 2 columns. I think I don't profit from `yield` in this case because I'm waiting `result` to be filled before using it.