# Using list comprehension to create sublists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have some .csv files that I'm reading and append each column to a different list.

#### .csv file example:

```
0, 1
2, 3
4, 5
```

#### Working Python code

```py
lst_a = []
lst_b = []
with open(csv_file, 'r') as f_read:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(f_read, delimiter = ',')
    for row in csv_reader:
        lst_a.append(float(row[0]))
        lst_b.append(float(row[1]))

print(lst_a)  # [0, 2, 4]
print(lst_b)  # [1, 3, 5]
```

I want to use list comprehension instead of the `for loop`to speed up things a little bit since I'm reading millions of .csv files. However, no success so far. I was able to get a list of lists but that's not what I want: `csv_file_list = [[float(i) for i in row] for row in csv_reader]`

Comment: are you opposed to using a library like pandas ?

Comment: Yes, it's extremely slow. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60059452/load-csv-then-return-list-of-rows).

Comment: If you're reading millions of files then it's just gonna be slow (especially in python). You might want to consider your design, do you actually need these two massive lists, or can you process the data as you iterate etc.

Comment: @Raphael interestingly enough according to timeit, pandas does this better than your current code as long as the csv file has enough lines. When your csv file had 3 lines your code works much better but once i expanded my csv to ~5k lines a simple pandas implementation was about twice as fast. (according to timeit)

Comment: @Chris_Rands I need to perform some calculation in two lists with 500 rows 5M times. I was using one single json file but I began to have memory issues. Then I saved all in a hdf5 file, it was super slow, so I kept using 5M individual .csv files.

Comment: @KaranShishoo I searched for other pandas benchmarks and they are faster only for larger files as yours, in my case is a lot of small files (500 rows max).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not good practice or pretty python code, but:

```
[(lst_a.append(float(row[0])), lst_b.append(float(row[1]))) for row in csv_reader]
```

works. The reason this isn't recommended is because you are creating a list of `None` with side effects, and list comprehensions were designed to have simple functions with output and no side effects in the comprehension. The 'append' code only gets executed because the python interpreter tries to evaluate the list, even though the list is not needed. This is a situation the for loop was created for! But of course, the choice is yours.

Edit: Using zip is nice and concise:

```
lst_a, lst_b = [[float(i) for i in x] for x in zip(*csv_reader)]
```

BUT is not perfomant. This is because zip will iterate over the rows of the csv n times where n is the number of columns, whereas the for loop or list comprehension without zip won't. So if you have a csv of a million rows and 10 columns, this will slow you down a lot.

Comment: Thx, I was hoping to avoid the `append()`. If there's no other way I will keep the `for loop`.

Comment: as suggested, the only way I can see for that is using `zip`.
`lst_a, lst_b = *[[float(i) for i in x] for x in zip(*csv_reader)]`

Comment: There's an extra * in your code, without it it works fine, but no performance improvement when comparing to the `for loop` maybe it's because of `zip()`.

Comment: fixed that, thanks. Yes, thats the reason I didn't suggest zip to begin with, for a file with millions of rows, zip has to read every row before creating the list so it should be slower than my initial answer, which builds on one iteration on the rows

Comment: It's millions of files with ~500 rows, actually. I accepted the answer since it does what was asked. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `zip`! It will zip together all 1st elements, all 2nd elements...

```
>>> with open(csv_file, 'r') as f_read:
...     csv_reader = csv.reader(f_read, delimiter = ',')
...     print(list(zip(*csv_reader)))
... 
[('0', '2', '4'), ('1', '3', '5')]
```

`*csv_reader` - the star is list unpacking = we pass elements of the list as separate parameters. This makes it treat all sub-lists as input lists for `zip`.

Result of `zip` is a zip object - an generator that yields when it's iterated over, so I had to use `list()` to print the result.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with zip and a single pass through the reader:

```
lst_a,lst_b = map(list,zip(*(map(float,row) for row in csvReader)))
```

Comment: Thank you. Works fine, however it's slower due to map + zip.